# iphone push notifications using mosquitto

Tags: ios, push-notification, push, server-push, mqtt

i'm trying to run an mqqt client on iphone using mosquitto broker.
Has anyone ever run an MQTT client on an iPhone? Is there a specific client for iPhone? Or is it possible to compile libmosquitto to run on an iPhone? [link to libmosquitto library](http://mosquitto.org/man/libmosquitto-3.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an example iPhone mosquitto app on github, go crazy :-)

https://github.com/njh/marquette/

(and yes, it does use libmosquitto)